# Finding the limit of the solution of an initial value problem with

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP,
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}=y^{2021}-y^{2019},$$ with $y(-2021)=1/2019$.How can we find $\lim y(t)$ as $t$ approaches infinity?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You seem to be a reputed user and know the site policy very well.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(y-1)(y+1)(y^{2019})}dy=dt $.Then breaking into partial fractions gives us y in terms of t.However,i fail to see how i can obtain the limit in the implicit form

Answer (score 2):

You have an autonomous equation of the form $y' = f(y)$, with $f(y) = y^{2019}(y^2-1)$.
This equation has three constant solutions ($y=0$, $y=-1$, $y=1$). Moreover, by uniqueness, any other solution cannot intersect a constant solution.

Since your initial data lies between $0$ and $1$, your solution must satisfy $0 < y(t) < 1$.
Moreover, $f(y) < 0$ for every $y\in (0,1)$, hence your solution is decreasing, so that there exists $L := \lim_{t\to +\infty} y(t) \in [0,1/2019)$.
Finally, you can easily prove that $L = 0$. Similarly, you can prove that $\lim_{t\to -\infty} y(t) = 1$.